How to level the printer Creality LD 002R
Good afternoon. Tell me how to level the printer Creality LD 002R, the platform does not reach the tray, although z 0 is configured.  After all, the platform should be under the resin, at the bottom, when printing the first layers.
When the part is illuminated, it rises to the level of the highest resin mark in the tray, as a result, the first layer of printing ends up on the film in the tray. Since the illumination is coming, but the platform is outside the resin.
